# Cannot find the virtual function address of derived class in virtual function table

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, inheritance

This is the source code to observe the virtual function table:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base 
{
public:
    virtual void func() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
protected:
    int x;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Derived() {}
    virtual void func2() { cout << " func2() " << endl; }
protected:
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    Base b;
    Derived d;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I use the vs2012 and debug to the "cout << endl;" statement, then I find that the member function "func2" does not appear in the virtual function table, there are only Base::func() and Derived::~Derived().

[image]

Comment: You are looking at `d` -> `Base` -> `__vfptr`, but `Base`'s vtable has no need/place for `func2`. Check if you can find `Derived`'s vtable.

Comment: But there would be only one table which would be shared between the Base & Derived.

Comment: This is the whole object model for object d. I cannot find other vtable.

Comment: @MantoshKumar Yes and no. The vtable, as the object itself, is extended. If you look at it through `Base` (as the OP did in the debugger), you only see the first part which contains all the things `Base` knows about. You need to look at it through `Derived` to see the additional slots for `func2`, etc. This probably means that the debugger is simply too stupid to show all the information as the vtable-ptr is stored in the `Base`-part of the `Derived` instance and when the debugger tries to show it, it looses the information that `d` is `Derived` and could therefore use `Derived`'s vtable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It seems to be just a bug or weird behavior on Visual Studio's side.**

If you right-click on the `__vfptr` member and use "Add Watch" command in the context menu, you end up with a watch `(*((Base*)(&(d)))).__vfptr,nd`, showing the same.

Even if you change it to `(*((Derived*)(&(d)))).__vfptr,nd`, or just `d.__vfptr` for that matter, it still shows the same, even though Derived's vtable is bigger.

You need to explicitly specify the number of elements as 3 like this for it to finally show the rest of the table and your function: `d.__vfptr,3`

Comment: Thank you for your kindly reply, I followed this steps and found the address of func2() in the vtable.